# Creating traing and validation mini batch

Tags: python, image-preprocessing

```py
class Dataset(object):
    def __init__(self, X, y, batch_size, shuffle=False):
        """
        Construct a Dataset object to iterate over data X and labels y

        Inputs:
        - X: Numpy array of data, of any shape
        - batch_size: Integer giving number of elements per minibatch
        - shuffle: (optional) Boolean, whether to shuffle the data on each             
        """
        assert X.shape[0] == y.shape[0], 'Got different numbers of data and labels'
        self.X, self.y = X, y
        self.batch_size, self.shuffle = batch_size, shuffle

    def __iter__(self):
        N, B = self.X.shape[0], self.batch_size
        idxs = np.arange(N)
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(idxs)
        return iter((self.X[i:i+B], self.y[i:i+B]) for i in range(0, N, B))
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Do you get any error?

Comment: i don't understand how shuffling of data occur in __iter__